# Restrict email visibility on Portal

Tags: visualforce, email, customer-portal

The default implementation of the SalesForce customer portal shows all emails attached to a case to the customer.  Emails that were passed among my company employees only, for example, are shown as well.  I would like to implement a feature whereby I can shield these internal-only emails from the customer portal:

Combinations of email participants (any of from, to, cc):

```
joe@customer.com -> Support@example.com :  Visible
joe@customer.com, me@example.com        :  Visible
me@example.com, boss@example.com        :  Hidden
```

I do not want to prevent emails - I want to prevent Customer users on the portal from seeing emails sent between example.com participants.  Currently a portal user can see ALL emails attached to a case. I'd like to restrict that to just ones that include them or people at their company.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your diagram means?

Comment: email participants (any of from, to, cc)

Comment: How would you prevent someone from sending an email? Are you really talking about obscuring email addresses in profiles? When you say prevent email, can you clarify what mechanism specifically you're talking about for sending email?